# Gyroscope pitch and roll keep increasing even phone is steady in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, gyroscope

I am trying to get roll and pitch value from gyroscope sensor in android phone. Getting good result so far. But, even on steady mode, value keep increasing by small factor and after converting radian it shows big impact (increasing by 1 in every 5-10 seconds)

```
   // Ratio of nanosecond to second 
   private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;
   private static final float EPSILON = 0.001f;     

   if (this.timestamp != 0) {
      float dT = ((float) (gyroTimeStamp - this.timestamp)) * NS2S;
      float axisX = gyrations[0];
      float axisY = gyrations[1];
      float axisZ = gyrations[2];
      float omegaMagnitude = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (((axisX * axisX) + (axisY * axisY)) + (axisZ * axisZ)));
      if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
          axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
          axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
          axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
      }
      float thetaOverTwo = (omegaMagnitude * dT) / 2.0f;
      float sinThetaOverTwo = (float) Math.sin((double) thetaOverTwo);
      float cosThetaOverTwo = (float) Math.cos((double) thetaOverTwo);
      this.deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX;
      this.deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY;
      this.deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ;
      this.deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
  }
  this.timestamp = gyroTimeStamp;
  if (this.currentRotationSet) {
      float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
      SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
      this.currentRotationMatrix = multiplyMat3(this.currentRotationMatrix, deltaRotationMatrix);
      float[] r = rotations.clone();
      SensorManager.getOrientation(this.currentRotationMatrix, this.rotations);
      Log.i(TAG, "X: " + (rotations[0] - r[0]) + ", Y: " + (rotations[1] - r[1]));
      this.rotations[3] = 0.0f;

      this.roll = -this.rotations[2];
      this.pitch = this.rotations[1];
      return;
  }
  SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(this.currentRotationMatrix, this.deltaRotationVector);
  this.currentRotationSet = true;
  this.rotations[3] = 1.0f;
```

I am using it by converting it to radian:

```
float pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees((double) this.pitch);
float roll =(float) Math.toDegrees((double) this.roll);
```

I am sure this code adding delta on every calculation but I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html `In practice, gyroscope noise and drift will introduce errors that need to be compensated for. You usually determine the drift (bias) and noise by monitoring other sensors, such as the gravity sensor or accelerometer.`